# MySQL Error Code: 1452 when adding index and foreign key constraints to an existing table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database with an existing (and not removable) cities table with a new reference to a table province by a field province_id.

When I run:

```
ALTER TABLE cities ADD province_id INTEGER NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE cities ADD INDEX (province_id),
                   ADD FOREIGN KEY (province_id) REFERENCES provinces (id);
```

I got next error on the second query, adding the index and foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE cities ADD INDEX (province_id),        ADD FOREIGN KEY (province_id) REFERENCES provinces (id)  Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`yanpytest`.`#sql-16d8_325`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-16d8_325_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`province_id`) REFERENCES `provinces` (`id`))
```

I don´t understand why, and this is not working in my production environment, in development it worked (both MySQL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably means that in the `province_id` column in the `cities` table you have some value(s) e.g. 123 which does not exist in the `provinces` table in the `id` column there. So the foreign key (FK) constraint cannot be enforced by MySQL and it fails on you.

You can find the violating records by running:

```
SELECT * FROM `cities` WHERE `province_id` NOT IN 
(SELECT id FROM `provinces`)
```